# Accounting Calculate Debit credit in SQL(ssms)

Tags: sql, sql-server, accounting, issuu

I have an accounting calculation problem. I want to write it with SQL Query (in ssms).
I have two groups of documents related to one person (creditor and debtor)
Creditor documents cover debtor documents.
Consider the following example: (How can the result be achieved?)

```sql
USE [master]
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #credit/*creditor=0*/,#debit/*Debtor=1*/

SELECT *
INTO #debit
FROM    (values 
        (88,'2/14',1,5,1),(88,'2/15',2,5,1)
        )A (personID,DocDate,DocID,Fee,IsDebit)

SELECT *
INTO #credit
FROM    (values 
        (88,'2/16',3,3,0),(88,'2/17',4,7,0)
        )A (personID,DocDate,DocID,Fee,ISDeb)
SELECT * FROM #credit
SELECT * FROM #debit


--result:
;WITH res AS
(
    SELECT 88 AS personID ,1 deb_DocID ,5 deb_Fee , 3 Cre_DocID ,3 Cre_Fee, 0 remain_Cre_Fee
    UNION
    SELECT 88 AS personID ,1 deb_DocID ,5 deb_Fee , 4 Cre_DocID ,7 Cre_Fee, 5 remain_Cre_Fee
    UNION
    SELECT 88 AS personID ,2 deb_DocID ,5 deb_Fee , 4 Cre_DocID ,7 Cre_Fee, 0 remain_Cre_Fee
)


SELECT *
FROM res
```

Comment: So what is not working? What results are you expecting? I can't see any desired results in your question.

Comment: _Creditor documents cover debtor documents_ Means nothing to anyone but you. Is it relevant? And post actual DDL - not lazy, difficult to read <select into> queries that do not define primary and foreign keys and have no obvious relationships.  Next, '2/14' is NOT a date. Lazy habits simply lead to more problems.  Lastly, does a table named debit need a column named IsDebit? And a column named IsDeb (typo?) is confusing in a table named credit.

Comment: I made the result manually

Comment: This is Mini mini Test Query .This is not lazy. date is not real. `IsDebit` is field .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample data**

Using an ISO date format to avoid any confusion.

The `docdate` and `isdebit` columns will not be used in the solution...

1. I ignored the `docdate` under the *assumptions* that the values are incremental and that it is allow to deposit a credit fee before any debit fee.
2. The `isdebit` flag seems redundant if you are going to store debit and credit transactions in separate tables anyway.

Updated sample data:

```
create table debit
(
  personid int,
  docdate date,
  docid int,
  fee int,
  isdebit bit
);

insert into debit (personid, docdate, docid, fee, isdebit) values
(88, '2021-02-14', 1, 5, 1),
(88, '2021-02-15', 2, 5, 1);

create table credit
(
  personid int,
  docdate date,
  docid int,
  fee int,
  isdebit bit
);

insert into credit (personid, docdate, docid, fee, isdebit) values
(88, '2021-02-16', 3, 3, 0),
(88, '2021-02-17', 4, 7, 0);
```

**Solution**

Couple steps here:

1. Construct a rolling sum for the debit fees. Done with a first common table expression (`cte_debit`).
2. Construct a rolling sum for the credit fees. Done with a second common table expression (`cte_credit`).
3. Take all debit info (`select * from cte_debit`)
4. Find the *first* credit info that applies to the current debit info. Done with a first `cross apply` (`cc1`). This contains the `docid` of the first document that applies to the debit document.
5. Find the *last* credit info that applies to the current debit info. Done with a second `cross apply` (`cc2`). This contains the `docid` of the last document that applies to the debit document.
6. Find *all* credit info that applies to the current debit info by selecting all documents between the first and last applicable document (`join cte_credit cc on cc.docid >= cc1.docid and cc.docid <= cc2.docid`).
7. Combine the rolling sum numbers to calculate the remaining credit fees (`cc.credit_sum - cd.debit_sum`). Use a `case` expression to filter out negative values.

Full solution:

```
with cte_debit as
(
  select d.personid,
         d.docid,
         d.fee,
         sum(d.fee) over(order by d.docid rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as debit_sum
  from debit d
),
cte_credit as
(
  select c.personid,
         c.docid,
         c.fee,
         sum(c.fee) over(order by c.docid rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as credit_sum
  from credit c
)
select cd.personid,
       cd.docid as deb_docid,
       cd.fee as deb_fee,
       cc.docid as cre_docid,
       cc.fee as cre_fee,
       case
         when cc.credit_sum - cd.debit_sum >= 0
         then cc.credit_sum - cd.debit_sum
         else 0
       end as cre_fee_remaining
from cte_debit cd
cross apply ( select top 1 cc1.docid, cc1.credit_sum
              from cte_credit cc1
              where cc1.personid = cd.personid
                and cc1.credit_sum <= cd.debit_sum
              order by cc1.credit_sum desc ) cc1
cross apply ( select top 1 cc2.docid, cc2.credit_sum
              from cte_credit cc2
              where cc2.personid = cd.personid
                and cc2.credit_sum >= cd.debit_sum
              order by cc2.credit_sum desc ) cc2
join cte_credit cc
  on  cc.personid = cd.personid
  and cc.docid >= cc1.docid
  and cc.docid <= cc2.docid
order by cd.personid,
         cd.docid,
         cc.docid;
```

**Result**

```
personid  deb_docid  deb_fee  cre_docid  cre_fee  cre_fee_remaining
--------  ---------  -------  ---------  -------  -----------------
88        1          5        3          3        0
88        1          5        4          7        5
88        2          5        4          7        0
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3da3424c4a2f775c10b3dd75a4e56fc2) to see things in action. This also contains the intermediate CTE results and some commented helper columns that can be uncommented to help to further understand the solution.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time